# XSLT 1.0 count following-siblings

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a simple xml like this

```
  <root>
          <story>
            <strongp>
                <color>Attention</color>
                Text of the single strongp color.
            </strongp>
            <p>Text</p>
            <strongp>
                <color>Attention</color>
                Text of strongp color.
            </strongp>
            <strongp>
                Text of interest1
                <a id="1234-3457">here</a>.
            </strongp>
            <p>sometext</p>
            <p>sometext</p>
            <el>sometext</el>
            <h5>Header H5</h5>
            <strongp>
                <color>Attention</color>
                Text of strongp color.
            </strongp>
            <strongp>
                Text of interest 
                <a id="8909-3490">here</a>
            </strongp>
            <strongp>
                Text of interest 
                <a id="8909-0081">here</a>
            </strongp>
            <strongp>
                Text of interest 
                <a id="8967-001">here</a>
            </strongp>
            <p>Text</p>

            <inline />
         </story>
  </root>
```

Need to transform `strongp[color]` into `remarkheader` and the following siblings into `remarktext` and wrap this all to `<remark>`.

The output required for the single `<strongp>` with color:

```
<remark>
    <remarkheader>Attention</remarkheader>
    <remarktext>Text of the single  strongp color.</remarktext>
</remark>
```

And the output for `strongp with color` followed by 1 sibling `strongp` is:

```
<remark>
    <remarkheader>Attention</remarkheader>
    <remarktext>Text of strongp color.<br/>Text of interest1
                <a id="1234-3457">here</a>.</remarktext>
</remark>
```

Finally output for `strongp color` followed by more than 1 `strongp`

```
<remark>
    <remarkheader>Attention</remarkheader>
    <remarktext>
        Text of strongp color.
        <br/>
        Text of interest1
        <a id="1234-3457">here</a>.
    <br/>
        Text of interest
        <a id="8909-3490">here</a>.
    <br/>
        Text of interest
        <a id="8909-0081">here</a>.
    <br/>
        Text of interest
        <a id="8967-001">here</a>.
    </remarktext>
</remark>
```

Well, applied this template

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="strongp[color]">
        <remark>
            <remarkheader>
                <xsl:value-of select="./color"/>
            </remarkheader>
            <remarktext>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., color)"/>
                <br/>
                <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::strongp[count(preceding-sibling::strongp[color][1] | current())=1]">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()"  />
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position() !=last()">
                            <br/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </remarktext>
        </remark>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it doesn't seem to work fine. It adds a text from first following sibling `strongp[color]`. I really don't understand how it counts the following-sibling.

You can look at it here
http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=c1b3e857-b6d7-4562-a440-9d3e357cb12d-xsltransformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try, processing `following-sibling::strongp` recursively:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="strongp[color]">
    <remark>
        <remarkheader>
            <xsl:value-of select="color"/>
        </remarkheader>
        <remarktext>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::strongp]" mode="following"/>
        </remarktext>
    </remark>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="strongp" mode="following">
    <br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::strongp]" mode="following"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="strongp"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```